# randomly split dictionary into n parts

Tags: r, split, quanteda

I have a `quanteda` dictionary I want to randomly split into `n` parts.

```
dict <- dictionary(list(positive = c("good", "amazing", "best", "outstanding", "beautiful", "wonderf*"),
            negative = c("bad", "worst", "awful", "atrocious", "deplorable", "horrendous")))
```

I have tried using the `split` function like this: `split(dict, f=factor(3))` but was not successful.

I would like to get three dictionaries back but I get

```
$`3`
Dictionary object with 2 key entries.
- [positive]:
  - good, amazing, best, outstanding, beautiful, wonderf*
- [negative]:
  - bad, worst, awful, atrocious, deplorable, horrendous
```

**EDIT**

I have included a different entry containing `*` in the dictionary. The solution suggested by [Ken Benoit](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4158274/ken-benoit) throws an error in this case but works perfectly fine otherwise.

The desired output is something like this:

```
> dict_1
Dictionary object with 2 key entries.
- [positive]:
  - good, wonderf*
- [negative]:
  - deplorable, horrendous

> dict_2
Dictionary object with 2 key entries.
- [positive]:
  - amazing, best
- [negative]:
  - bad, worst

> dict_3
Dictionary object with 2 key entries.
- [positive]:
  - outstanding, beautiful
- [negative]:
  - awful, atrocious
```

In case the number of entries cannot be divided by `n` without remainders, I have no specification but *ideally* I would be able to decide that I want (i) the 'remainder' separately or (ii) that I want all values to be distributed (which results in some splits being slightly larger).

Comment: Can you please provide an example of the desired output?

Comment: Yes we need more specifics on what you want to get out of it. Multiple keys for positive and negative, each containing subsets? Are remainder values ok (since the number of values for a key might not be a multiple of the split size)?

Comment: Thank you for the feedback and apologies for being unclear. I amended the question accordingly and hope it is clearer now.

Comment: How would you handle keys with values of different lengths then? Should we assume equal lengths?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a lot unspecified in the question since with dictionary keys of different lengths it's unclear how this should be handled, and since there is no pattern to the pairs in your expected answer.

Here, I've assumed you have keys of equal length, divisible by the split without a remainder, and that you want to split it in running, adjacent intervals for each dictionary key.

This should do it.

```r
library("quanteda")
## Package version: 1.5.1

dict <- dictionary(
  list(
    positive = c("good", "amazing", "best", "outstanding", "beautiful", "delightful"),
    negative = c("bad", "worst", "awful", "atrocious", "deplorable", "horrendous")
  )
)

dictionary_split <- function(x, len) {
  maxlen <- max(lengths(x)) # change to minumum to avoid recycling
  subindex <- split(seq_len(maxlen), ceiling(seq_len(maxlen) / len))
  splitlist <- lapply(subindex, function(y) lapply(x, "[", y))
  names(splitlist) <- paste0("dict_", seq_along(splitlist))
  lapply(splitlist, dictionary)
}

dictionary_split(dict, 2)
## $dict_1
## Dictionary object with 2 key entries.
## - [positive]:
##   - good, amazing
## - [negative]:
##   - bad, worst
## 
## $dict_2
## Dictionary object with 2 key entries.
## - [positive]:
##   - best, outstanding
## - [negative]:
##   - awful, atrocious
## 
## $dict_3
## Dictionary object with 2 key entries.
## - [positive]:
##   - beautiful, delightful
## - [negative]:
##   - deplorable, horrendous
```

Comment: awesome, thank you. When splitting a dictionary including entries with `*`, this solution throws an error (`Error in check_entries(x) : Non-character entries found in dictionary key 'positive'`). I've tried some string conversion but to no avail. Am I missing something obvious? [I have also edited the question to include one such entry.]

Comment: When I add * to the end of some of the dictionary values, the code above still works fine on my system, so I cannot replicate the error you mention above.